# Schedule to copy all id of Table A to Table B for weekly and insert a date to Table B Laravel

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks

What I'm intending to do is to make a task scheduling for weekly, which is to copy all of id from table `route_schedule` and insert into table `route_schedule_details` as FK, which then will insert the date of the weeks. This is how the route_schedule_details schema:

```
Schema::create('route_scheduler_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->dateTime('schedule_date')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('route_scheduler_mstr_id')->nullable()->index('FK_route_scheduler_details_route_scheduler_mstr');

        $table->foreign(['route_scheduler_mstr_id'], 'FK_route_scheduler_details_route_scheduler_mstr')->references(['id'])->on('route_scheduler_mstr')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

I never used task scheduling before so I'm little bit under-knowledged here. Read in Laravel docs, I have to add the schedule in `App/Console/Kernel.php`

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $data = [];
        $copies = RouteSchedulerMSTR::select('id')->get();
        foreach($copies as $copy){
            //I'm not sure what to do in here
        }

    })->weekly(1, '1:00');
}
```

Comment: there(inside foreach) you can insert to your table 'route_schedule_details'  then run cron 'php artisan schedule:run'

Comment: Ohh is there any way for me to insert the date for a week too?

Comment: of course , another away - create command and write your function and directly run with cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to create command because above your code can't test work or not :

```
php artisan make:command RouteSchedulerWeekly
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Models\RouteSchedulerMSTR;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class RouteSchedulerWeekly extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'routeschedule:weekly';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Run route scheduler weekly';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $copies = RouteSchedulerMSTR::select('id')->get();
        foreach($copies as $copy){
            DB::table('route_scheduler_details')->insert([
               'data' => now(),
               'route_scheduler_mstr_id' => $copy
            ]);
            $this->info('Route scheduler inserting...');
        }
        $this->info('Done!');
    }
}
```

Then you can test your code insert or not :

```php
php artisan routeschedule:weekly
```

if you wanted function is correct, you can run by cronjob with 2 options

1. Direct run command with cron

```
crontab -e
```

and add below script to crontab file on your server:

```
0 1 * * 6 cd /var/www/your-project && php artisan routeschedule:weekly >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

You can test crontab script [here](https://crontab.guru/#0_1_*_*_6)

In Windows use Task Scheduler

**OR**

2. Run with `schedule:run`

Add your command in `Kernel`

```php
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('routeschedule:weekly')->weekly(1, '1:00');
    }
}
```

and add below script to crontab file on your server:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

here * * * * * is every minute

Conclusion: I recommend option 1 that will run once in a week on your server. The option 2 also run once in a week your command but `schedule:run` running every minute

Comment: Thanks for the code, its working when I test it either its insert or not. But is there any possibility if I able to run in localhost?

Comment: If you use ubuntu you can test with `crontab` and if you use window you can use Task scheduler [tutorial](https://quantizd.com/how-to-use-laravel-task-scheduler-on-windows-10/) here